# AS3 - Score counter ad block's fall

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game with Flash Pro CS6 where you need to avoid falling cubes. When you've avoided une cube (cube_1) you get a point. I've made a scoreCounter texfield and setted it like a dynamic text. I didn't know how to tell Flash that when te animation of the movie clip "cube_1" was finished, it should have added a point, so I made an if statement that, depending of the cube's Y coordinate (> than the stage Y), you get a point. The problem is that I don't get any point!

The code is this:

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, cubeFall);

function cubeFall(t:TimerEvent) {
time++;
if (time == 3) {
    cube_1.play();
} else if (time == 10) {
    cube_2.play();
} else if (time == 20) {
    cube_3.play();
} else if (time == 30) {
    cube_4.play();
} else if (time == 35) {
    cube_5.play();
} else if (time == 40) {
    cube_6.play();
} else if (time == 50) {
    cube_7.play();
} else if (time == 60) {
    cube_8.play();
}

// Add Score

else if (cube_1.y > 480 || cube_2.y > 480 || cube_3.y > 480 || cube_4.y > 480 || cube_5.y > 480 || cube_6.y > 480 || cube_7.y > 480 || cube_8.y > 480 ) {
    score++;
    scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;
}
```

}

Comment: Add a line `trace(cube_1.y);` somewhere, so you'll find out the actual `y`-values of `cube_1`

Comment: It might help to start the timer as well. example: timer.start();

Comment: Travis, I started it before :)

Comment: Old question, but take out the `else`.